# Styling of Mirage 2 using themes from bootswatch.com

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dspace

Based from the [**Readme files**](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/readme.md#style) of Mirage 2, it says here:

If you want to base your theme on an existing Bootstrap theme (like the ones at [bootswatch.com](http://bootswatch.com/)) you can do so by using the standard Bootstrap color scheme and replacing the import of Bootstrap in `bootstrap_color_scheme/_main.scss`:

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

with an import of just its `_variables.sccs` file (those variables need to be defined, because they are used in `_dspace-bootstrap-tweaks.scss`):

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables";
```

Then import the the css file(s) of your Bootstrap theme of choice below it. Depending on the theme you may also need to update the twbs-font-path function right above that import statement.

**What I did:**

Ok, so I activated the `mirage2_bootstrap_color_scheme` maven profile. Copied the `bootstrap_color_scheme/_main.scss` from `dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/` into `dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage2/styles`.

I changed the text in `_main.scss` that says `@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";` into `@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables";`, and then I copied the `bootstrap.min.css` that I downloaded from bootswatch.com and put it in the same directory with `_main.scss` and then I referenced it in `_main.scss` with an `@import "bootstrap.min.css";` statement.

I'm having this error when running `mvn package`:

```
error styles/main.scss (Line 12: File to import not found or unreadable: variables.`
```

I also tried putting the `_variables.scss` under the `bootstrap_color_scheme` directory and used the `@import "variables";` but I got the same not found or unreadable error.

Can someone guide me on how to correctly use the themes from bootswatch.com to apply to Mirage 2? An example and a simple walk through of using a sample theme from bootswatch.com would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my other answer because I was mistaken.
Here is an example of a working bootswatch theme:
https://github.com/antoine-atmire/DSpace/tree/mirage2%2Bbootswatch/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage2/styles

The `/styles/bootstrap_color_scheme/_main.scss` file gets copied to `/styles/main.scss` during the build process, so the @import statements should be relative to `/styles/main.scss`.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, based on your sample `/styles/bootstrap_color_scheme/_main.scss`, would this mean that compass will use the `_variables.scss` from `vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/` and not the `_variables.scss` that comes with the theme from bootswatch? I'm confused from the readme that says: **with an import of just its `_variables.sccs` file (those variables need to be defined, because they are used in `_dspace-bootstrap-tweaks.scss`):** I thought I should use the `_variables.scss` from the bootswatch theme.

Comment: You're not wrong. `_dspace-bootstrap-tweaks.scss` only uses a few variables that are not very likely to be different in the bootswatch version. So it just adds more complexity to get it done.
If you're up for it and want to use the bootswatch source files, you could just as well import all of them instead of importing the bootswatch.min.css.

Comment: Thanks Antoine for the clarification. I have a question regarding updating of the `twbs-font-path`. I changed it to `"../../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/" + $font-name` because it is where the glyphicons are saved after building. It seems it has no effect because the css from bootswatch overrides it. As a result, the glyphicons were not showing because the css from bootswatch referenced it in `../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` What should I change in twbs-font-path such that I don't have to import fonts since it is already there and without editing the css?

Comment: Those glyphicon links are broken, indeed. This will have to be fixed. Meanwhile you can add the required font files in `/styles/fonts`, or you can change the links to the font files in the bootswatch.min.css... changing `twbs-font-path` does not have an effect on them

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap-sass has updated its paths, and the Mirage 2 docs are not yet updated.

_variables.scss is now stored here: "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss"

Depending on which version you're using, it can even be in another place.

A general recommendation is to look at the vendor folder in:
dspace/modules/xmlui/target/xmlui-*/themes/Mirage2/vendor/

Look for the path of the variables file there and use that path.

Comment: Thanks for the info Bram. I'm wondering how could I update the twbs-font-path? I'm referring to the statement from the Readme that says: **Depending on the theme you may also need to update the twbs-font-path function right above that import statement.** Can you please give me an example for this? Thanks again.