# DSpace Mirage2 - Where do I place a variable override?

Tags: dspace

I would like to override a Sass variable in my DSpace Mirage 2 theme to understand how to customize the theme.

If I want to make the following changes, where should I place them?

`$brand-primary: #607890;
$navbar-inverse-bg: #607890;
$navbar-inverse-link-color: yellow;`

I have tried adding a variable declaration in several locations, but it is not included in the compiled CSS file.

I am able to add new CSS rules to styles/_styles.scss and those rules are built into the the final CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the classic_mirage_color_scheme the [Bootstrap variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) are set in `classic_mirage_color_scheme/bootstrap_variables` so you could simply copy the file to `/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage2/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_bootstrap_variables.scss`.
The classic_mirage_color_scheme also defines a couple of its own variables in `classic_mirage_color_scheme/_dspace_variables.scss`. This would be a good place to add your non-bootstrap variables too.

The bootstrap_color_scheme doesn't override or define any variables. So when you start from the bootstrap_color_scheme you'd need to override in bootstrap_color_scheme/_main.scss like you did. (Beware the relative paths for importing files cfr. [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210988/styling-of-mirage-2-using-themes-from-bootswatch-com))

The variables are all set with `!default`, this means they're only set if they haven't been set before. That's why overriding the variables only works before the imports. 
Because the classic_mirage_color_scheme imports `_bootstrap_variables.scss` before `_dspace_variables.scss`, variables set in the latter won't be set if they have been set in the first.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work.

COPY

/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapps/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_main.scss

TO

/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage2/styles/classic_mirage_color/scheme/_main.scss

And add the variable declaration at the top before the includes.