# How do you change the Mirage 2 bootstrap theme on DSpace 6.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dspace

I am trying to replace the default Mirage 2 theme on my DSpace repository with one of those from bootswatch.com . I started by editing my _main.scss file

> [dspace-source]\dspace\modules\xmlui-mirage2\src\main\webapp\themes\Mirage2\styles\styles\bootstrap_color_scheme\

to import the new theme as follows:

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables";
@import "bootswatch.min.css";
```

Then I found (or think i found) the locations to copy both the bootstrap.min.css and the variables.scss files in the source. 
I have the copied bootstrap.min.css file to:

> [dspace-source]\dspace\modules\xmlui-mirage2\src\main\webapp\themes\Mirage2\styles\styles\

And the _variables.scss file to:

> [dspace-source]\dspace\modules\xmlui-mirage2\target\xmlui-mirage2-6.2\themes\Mirage2\vendor\bootstrap-sass-official\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap\

I get no errors while building but the older theme is still persistent. Note: I restart my servlet and clear both the Tomcat and browser cache before deploying the webapp. What could be the problem?

Comment: The following documentation might help.  https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2

Comment: Please post the answer that you discover for this question.  I am sure that the question will come up again for another DSpace developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you did not activate the `mirage2_bootstrap_color_scheme` maven profile? Try adding `-P mirage2_bootstrap_color_scheme` when rebuilding ie `mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true -Dmirage2.deps.included=false -P mirage2_bootstrap_color_scheme`.

> Mirage 2 contains two color schemes to choose from. The classic Mirage color scheme or the standard Bootstrap color scheme. By default, Grunt will build CSS to get the classic Mirage color scheme. However, by activating the mirage2_bootstrap_color_scheme maven profile, this can be changed to get the standard Bootstrap color scheme.

Also, maybe these post can help you: [Styling of Mirage 2 using themes from bootswatch.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27210988/1919069)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you haven't changed the `grunt.color.scheme` in `dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/pom.xml` ?

I once made [an example branch](https://github.com/antoine-atmire/DSpace/commits/dspace6-bootswatch). Please have a look at this commit:
https://github.com/antoine-atmire/DSpace/commit/28fd746621768c5e9a92d6d75399e0992858e651

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help guys! Managed to solve the problem. In Dspace 6.2 changes are actually applied in the

> [dspace-src]\dspace-xmlui-mirage2

folder. Therefore the *_main.scss* file that will be edited will be in

> [dspace-src]\dspace-xmlui-mirage2\src\main\webapp\styles\bootstrap_color_scheme

folder and not

> [dspace-src]\dspace

Also (*this is just my take but*) after getting perrenial syntax errors after deploying the site, I decided to convert the *bootstrap.min.css* file that i got from bootswatch into a .scss

Lastly, i run maven from [dspace-src] and not [dspace-src]\dspace
(as the files that im working with are found outside that folder) as follows:

```
mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true -Dmirage2.deps.included=true -P mirage2_bootstrap_color_scheme
```

No errors, and the theme works okay ! I'm currently just ironing out some kinks :)